# How do i properly attach a .PNG file into a TKINTER button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I am doing a battleship game and a function below that executes to create a new button with an explosion image as it's background. I am using Mac & python 3.7

```
global redraw_gameboard
global Player
global AI_player    

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "explode.png"

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path))

new_button = Button(redraw_gameboard, 
                    height = 2, 
                    width = 4, 
                    command= already_shot,
                    image=image)

new_button.grid(row = row, column = column)
```

This is what is coming out:

[image]

Comment: Try using pillow module

Comment: If the code is inside a function, you need to keep a reference to `image`.  Try adding `new_button.image = image`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks buddy, it finally worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you expect, since I don't know what does the "explode.png" image look like. Also, when asking questions on stackoverflow, please always try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

However, as I understand, the problem probably comes from the fact that the image is bigger than the button, and it is cropped. Then, only the upper left part of the image is displayed in your buttons.

Suggested solution:
(You will need to install the pillow package if it is not done yet)

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter

# Sizes in pixels
BUTTON_HEIGHT = 40
BUTTON_WIDTH = 40

root = tkinter.Tk()

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "explode.png"

image = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path))
image = image.resize((BUTTON_WIDTH,BUTTON_HEIGHT))
imtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

# Using a void image for other buttons so that the size is given in pixels too
void_imtk = tkinter.PhotoImage(width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT)


def create_button(row, column, im):
    new_button = tkinter.Button(root,
                                height = BUTTON_HEIGHT,
                                width = BUTTON_WIDTH,
                                image=im)
    new_button.grid(row = row, column = column)


create_button(0,0, imtk)
create_button(0,1, void_imtk)
create_button(1,0, void_imtk)
create_button(1,1, imtk)


root.mainloop()
```

Of course, you will want to make some changes for your program, e.g. using your widget architecture.